# Obtain DataTable from existing Google visualization chart

Tags: google-visualization

I have drawn a Google visualization table chart. How can I get the DataTable that is used to draw the chart? For example, how to get the value of first 5 rows and column 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the [ChartWrapper](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#chartwrapperobject) you can get the DataTable like this:

```
  var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    dataTable: [['Germany', 'USA', 'Brazil', 'Canada', 'France', 'RU'],
                [700, 300, 400, 500, 600, 800]],
    options: {'title': 'Countries'},
    containerId: 'visualization'
  });
  wrapper.draw();
  // get the DT
  var dt = wrapper.getDataTable();
  console.log(dt);
```

If you want to get a value from the DataTable, you can use the `getValue(rowIndex, columnIndex)` method of a DataTable:

```
var dt = wrapper.getDataTable();
alert(dt.getValue(3, 1));
```

Comment: How to construct the warpper from existing chart, that is, the datatable is already discarded?

Comment: I'm not sure I get you.. you mean, get the DataTable from a chart that is already drawn on the page? Can you include your code in the post and show where the problem is?

Comment: I mean, I draw the chart in one function, and is there a way to use ChartWrapper in another function (without using global variable)?

Comment: That's up to you really. I might do something using namespacing; at the top of my script like: `var myapp = {};` then maybe `mayapp.visualizations = {};` then when you draw your chart: `mayapp.visualizations.myChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(... rest of code ...)`. Then you can reference it elsewhere. Though, that's more of a management issue, as opposed to gviz.